# cite author-year with IEEEbib.bst bibliography style

Tags: bibtex

I have a bibliography I want to be displayed by IEEEbib.bst (or unsrt), but I want the citations to be [author, year] and not [number].

I tried using `\usepackage{natbib}` with `\citep` etc. but then I have to use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, and if I use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}` or unsrt, I can't use author-date.

So how can I do both author-date citations and IEEEbib.bst bibliography style?

MWE: (beamer style)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\citep{author1}
\citet{author2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} {Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{library}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make `IEEEbib.bst` work as an author-year citation style, but you can use one of the derived styles in the [IEEEtran](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) bundle. Both `IEEEtranN` and `IEEEtranSN` provide an author-year style that can be used in conjunction with `natbib`, the first listing the references "unsorted" (in order of appearance), the second one sorted by author.